# Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$pdo

Tags: php, pdo, laravel, laravel-4

What is this error and how to catch it?

```
Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$pdo
```

Heres my code:

```
if($user->save())
        {
            try
            {
                DB::connection()->pdo->beginTransaction();

                Mymodel::insert('credit-card',array('user_id'=>$user->id,'card_holder'=>Input::get('custname')));
                Mymodel::insert('billing-info',array('user_id'=>$user->id,'name'=>Input::get('custname')));

                DB::connection()->pdo->commit();

                Auth::login( $user );
                return Redirect::to( 'profile' );
            }
            catch (\PDOException $e)
            {
                $user->delete();
                DB::connection()->pdo->rollBack();
                return 'ERROR: Something went wrong. Please try again later';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to catch it?

You can not catch it - `Exceptions` are catchable, this is an ordinary error.

> What is this error

Here:

```
DB::connection()->pdo->beginTransaction();
```

You are trying to directly access `pdo` property of an object returned by `DB::connection()`. This property is declared as protected to prevent accessing it directly and manipulate in a way that can result in unpredictable behavior of entire framework.

From the [quick look at source code](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Connection.html#395-426) it looks that transaction can be achieved like this:

```
DB::connection()->transaction(function() use($user){
    Mymodel::insert('credit-card',array('user_id'=>$user->id,'card_holder'=>Input::get('custname')));
    Mymodel::insert('billing-info',array('user_id'=>$user->id,'name'=>Input::get('custname')));
});
```

Comment: I am also planning to do this kind of approach however I am after the `catch` part where i can display error messages. what is the proper way to do it into your given code?
REF: [http://laravelish.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/how-to-make-database-transaction-with-laravel/]

Comment: your try/catch block can stay, every exception thrown by `MyModel::insert` will be rethrown and you can catch it. Just remove `DB::connection()->pdo->rollBack();` from it. Also note that your referenced article is tagged `laravel-3` - most likely it was changed in newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use getPdo() instead of pdo in each statements becuase The pdo 
property is now protected. Get it by using the getPdo() method.

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->beginTransaction();
 ........
 ........
DB::connection()->getPdo()->commit();
......
......
DB::connection()->getPdo()->rollBack();
```